# How to make a game unit travel to a point in a straight diagonal line?

Tags: java, game-engine, game-physics

I'm coding a Pacman game for my final project in my OOP class this semester. I've gotten quite a bit done, but now I'm implementing the feature where the ghosts turn into those "wiggly eyes" and travel straight back to the ghost house.

In order to implement this, I know I need two points: one where I want the ghost to go (this is called the ghost's startTile in my code), as well as the ghost's current position. From there, we can calculate the X/Y distance. I know I need to do something along these lines, just not sure what.

This is the code I'm currently using to try and achieve this:

```
double xDistance = Math.abs(startTile.x*16+8 - position.getCenterX());
double yDistance = Math.abs(startTile.y*16+8 - position.getCenterY());
double xRatio = xDistance / yDistance;
double yRatio = yDistance / xDistance;
if((int)Math.round(startTile.x*16+8) < (int)Math.round(position.getCenterX())) {
  position.setDirection(DIRECTION_WEST);
  position.step(movementPixels*xRatio);
} else if((int)Math.round(startTile.x*16+8) > (int)Math.round(position.getCenterX())) {
  position.setDirection(DIRECTION_EAST);
  position.step(movementPixels*xRatio);
}
if((int)Math.round(startTile.y*16+8) < (int)Math.round(position.getCenterY())) {
  position.setDirection(DIRECTION_NORTH);
  position.step(movementPixels*yRatio);
} else if((int)Math.round(startTile.y*16+8) > (int)Math.round(position.getCenterY())) {
  position.setDirection(DIRECTION_SOUTH);
  position.step(movementPixels*yRatio);
}
System.out.println(position.getTileX() + " == " + startTile.x + " && " + position.getTileY() + " == " + startTile.y);
if(position.getTileX() == startTile.x && position.getTileY() == startTile.y) {
  setNewLife();
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. In fact, they move all crazy weird, and eventually end up shooting off to the side of the map somewhere, at which point the position.getTileY() will return a value like 2173454 or something insane...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem (still looking at it), but you can store the values for `startTile.x*16+8`, `position.getCenterX()`, `startTile.y*16+8`, and `position.getCenterY()` in variables so you don't have to calculate each one a bunch of times in one call to your function. You could go even further and store the rounded values in variables too.

Comment: Can you post initial conditions and the output of the last `System.out.println` statement for some iterations?